# Possible to clone TFS project with Android Studio

Tags: git, tfs, android-studio, azure-devops

I just setup a new TFS project with Git support on `https://[account].visualstudio.com` and have installed the lasted version of Android Studio.

I am trying to clone the new project through Android studio by going:

```
VCS -> Checkout from Version Control -> Git
```

I then put in the same url as above,  `https://[account].visualstudio.com` and `https://[account].visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/[projectname]`, as the git repo url and entered the appropiate user name and password but get the error: `Repository test` failed.

Am I getting this error because I'm going through the process incorrectly or because its not possible to clone the TFS project from Android Studio?

I know its possible with Eclipse but really like the new Android Studio and hoped to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I didn't have my secondary credentials setup. From the visualstudio website:

> Note: To clone and use this repository from Git tools outside Visual
>   Studio, you need to ensure alternate credentials are enabled in the
>   Profile dialog.

Once I added that I was able to clone the repo without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem 'repository test failed'. But I already had alternate credentials setup.

The problem was not having a vaild git.exe on my PC(!) - I assumed it would be installed by visual studio, android studio etc as required - seems it isnt.

I installed github for windows, but this uses various 'clever' windows installation/launch features which means you don't have a simple git.exe in a well known location to use.

So I uninstalled github for windows and installed git for windows from https://msysgit.github.io/ (note installed git for windows, not msysgit itself).

This put git.exe in C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe

So from android studio, setting, version control, I set this up as the path to git.exe (link to the actual file, not just the path).

Testing the link prompted for username password - etc - so fixed.

NB: I don't know for sure that the default credentials wouldn't work as I didn't actually try that - went straight for the alternate.